# How to speed up this slow query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, explain

I designed a mysql db and loaded some data (perhaps 10 mio rows in total).
I am trying to get data from two tables where time intervals overlap.

```
SELECT 
        cd.ParameterID,
        intervals.TimeStamp,
        intervals.GreenHouseID,
        intervals.TargetParam,
        intervals.ProductionID
FROM
        (
                SELECT 
                        pd.TimeStamp, 
                        p.GreenHouseID, 
                        pd.ParameterID AS TargetParam, 
                        pd.ProductionID
                FROM 
                        Production p INNER JOIN 
                        ProductionData pd ON pd.ProductionID=p.ID
                GROUP BY
                        pd.TimeStamp, p.GreenHouseID
        ) AS intervals,
    ClimateData cd
WHERE
        DATE_FORMAT(intervals.TimeStamp,'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(cd.Time_stamp,'%Y-%m-%d') AND
        cd.GreenHouseID = intervals.GreenHouseID
GROUP BY
        intervals.ProductionID, intervals.TargetParam
```

Unfortunately, the query takes too long (I didn't see it finish, yet).

When I use `EXPLAIN` I get the following result:

```
|id|select_type|table     |partitions|type |possible_keys|key          |key_len|ref                   |rows|filtered|Extra
|1|PRIMARY     |<derived2>|NULL      |ALL  |NULL         |NULL         |NULL   |NULL                  | 416|  100.00|Using where Using temporary
|1|PRIMARY     |cd        |NULL      |ref  |cd_ghid_idx  |cd_ghid_idx  |4      |intervals.GreenHouseID|1660|  100.00|Using where       
|2|DERIVED     |p         |NULL      |index|PRIMARY      |pr_gh_fk_idx |5      |NULL                  |  13|  100.00|Using index Using temporary
|2|DERIVED     |pd        |NULL      |ref  |pd_pr_fk_idx |pd_pr_fk_idx |5      |ghdb.p.ID             |  32|  100.00|NULL
```

I believe I put indices on all relevant columns to ensure fast querying. The query I designed uses a temp table (`intervals`), however. Is that degrading the performance? If so, how to design a faster query?

The mysql server is on my laptop (16GB RAM, CPU E3-1505M v5). I did not make any changes to the mysql setup. Would that be useful?

I would like a result of the query in decent time (in a few minutes would be OK).

Thank you.

Comment: Your query is rife with problems.  Why are you using `GROUP BY`, if you're not aggregating anything.  I think you should include sample input data and the expected output.  Perhaps just rewriting your query properly would fix the performance issue.

Comment: Have you tried skipping the `DATE_FORMAT` condition? That might slow everything down, as for each line, the timestamp has to get formatted

Comment: why not join with  Production  cd.GreenHouseID = intervals.GreenHouseID

Comment: and group by 2 times makes it more slow

Comment: The date is in datetime format so I need to strip of the time to make it comparable on a daily basis. Or is there another way?

Comment: In MySQL, functions cannot use indexes, so joining on `function( column)` is never a good idea performancewise.

Comment: It is the date_format 'joining' that causes the performance issue. Without it it finishes in the fraction of a second.

Comment: You can change `DATE_FORMAT(...)` to `DATE(cd.Time_stamp)`. Also you can add a generated column with the date to the intervals table. This will allow a composite index on `GreenHouseID, date`.

Comment: @jallmer . . . This question has no answers and the query is rife with problems (as Tim points out).  I would suggest that you delete this question.  Ask another question providing sample data, desired results, and ask about the best way to write the query.  You might then want a follow-on question about performance.

Comment: The problem was solved avoiding joining on function results so my question is answered, alas not formally. There is nothing wrong with using `group by` without using any additional aggregation. Rewriting a query does not seem an informed suggestion to me as coming up with a query plan is the job of the DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, including the temp table.
- There appears to be a single-column index on the temp table?
- Temp versus permanent should make not difference in performance.  However, the extra step to create the temp table could take a toll.
- Say `NOT NULL` where appropriate.
- Hiding a column in a function call (`DATE_FORMAT` in your case) prevents use of an index -- hence the `ALL`.
- You can't "tune your way out of a performance problem", so I will not address tuning other than to ask the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.
- Please do not use "comma-join"; instead, use `JOIN .. ON ..`

The main performance issue is here:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(intervals.TimeStamp,'%Y-%m-%d') = 
      DATE_FORMAT(cd.Time_stamp,'%Y-%m-%d')
  AND cd.GreenHouseID = intervals.GreenHouseID
```

It needs to look more like

```
WHERE intervals.TimeStamp ...
  AND cd.GreenHouseID = intervals.GreenHouseID
```

Since you are going to the effort to construct `intervals` on the fly, have a column that contains just the date.  And you may as well compute it via `DATE(...)` instead of `DATE_FORMAT(...)`.

Since you are computing one of the dates, change `pd.TimeStamp` to

```
    DATE(pd.TimeStamp) AS TS_Date
```

Then,

```
WHERE intervals.TimeStamp >= cd.TS_Date
  AND intervals.TimeStamp  < cd.TS_Date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND intervals.GreenHouseID = cd.GreenHouseID
```

You will also need together with this 'composite' index on `intervals`:

```
INDEX(GreenHouseID, TimeStamp) -- in this order
```

Bug remaining:  I see `GROUP BY pd.TimeStamp, ...`; this does not make sense, so I am ignoring it.